# How use jquery getJSON with a local variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, ace-editor

i want to extend the completions of Ace Editor, and i need a json of word, this is my code:

```
function load_completions() {

        var object = $('#preview').attr('class');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test_editor_ajax.php",
            data: {action:'load_completion', object:object},
            cache: false,
            success: function(json){
                var adminCompleter = {
                    getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
                        if (prefix.length === 0) { callback(null, []); return }
                        $.getJSON(json, function(wordList) {
                            callback(null, wordList.map(function(ea)  {           
                                return {name: ea.word, value: ea.word, meta: "optional text"}
                            }));
                        })
                    }
                }
                langTools.addCompleter(adminCompleter);
            }
        });

        return false;

    }
```

the `getJSON` function require a url to a json file, but i have created the json locally with ajax, how you can see in the above code, the ajax call return a json that i generate in this way:

```
echo json_encode($completions);
```

and `$completions` is an array, so my question is how i can use it in that functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is JavaScript Object Notation, so this: `[]` or `{}` is JSON.

I guess you only need:

```
        getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {
            if (prefix.length === 0) {
              callback(null, []);
              return;
            }
            callback(null, wordList.map(function(ea)  {           
                return {name: ea.word, value: ea.word, meta: "optional text"}
            }));
        }
```

`$.getJSON` will call the server using AJAX. It's just a shorthand method for doing a GET request that accepts `application/json` in a response.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but where you use my json variable in your example code?

Comment: isn't `json` the same as `wordList`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript. Just parse it and you can access any of it like any other object.

Comment: @andrusieczko if i do json.map(function(ea) doesn't work...and give me error in console

Comment: @MarekLisý it's worked! i have to do var wordList = JSON.parse(json); thanks!